# Ruby: Check given input is positive or negative

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build a simple tip calculator. I am trying to verify whether my input is positive or negative number.

```
def isInt(num)
    return Integer(num) rescue nil
end

def isFloat(num)
    return Float(num) rescue nil
end 

puts "Enter bill amount"

billAmount = gets.chomp
billAmount = isInt(billAmount) || isFloat(billAmount)
    
  if !billAmount and !billAmount.to_i.positive?()
    puts "Error!! Please enter a valid bill amount."
    next # similar to continue
  end
```

I am trying to find out whether the user giving input as a positive number or negative number. I tried with `billAmount.positive?()`,  `billAmount.to_i.positive?()` and `if billAmount > 0`.

Nothing seems working for me.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but using `snake_case` for method names and variable names is a [strong community standard](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars) in Ruby :)

Comment: @Viktor, Thank you. I am from different programming language background. I will follow the ruby standards in my learning.Thank you.

Comment: If you're dealing with money, why not just cast the input as a BigDecimal? Why do you care whether the value is a Float or an Integer? Also, don't reinvent the wheel. There's already a gem for handling [Money objects](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional statement contains two checks that cannot both be true:

```
 if !billAmount and !billAmount.to_i.positive?()
```

In ruby `!` means the inverse, i.e. `true` returns true and `!true` returns false.

Your first part of the conditional says 'If bill Amount is the opposite of not nil', or in simpler terms, 'Is billAmount nil?', which if it isn't nil, returns false

The second part is asking if `!billAmount.to_i.positive?()` is true. This is the same as writing `true.to_i.positive?` or `false.to_i.positive?`

I'd imagine you want something like:

```
unless billAmount&.to_i&.positive
```

This clause will only return true if either a bill amount returns nil, or after being converted to an integer, returns a non positive number.

The `&` syntax prevents ruby from throwing an error if the first part is nil (i.e. undefined method `to_i` for nilclass), instead simply returning nil (which evaluates as false)

Comment: I understand where I am doing it wrong. I replaced `and` with `||`. It's working now. Thank you.